# How to AutoFit column width with Google Sheets API?

Tags: google-sheets-api

Is there any way to AutoFit Column width in Google Sheets using Google Sheets API? 
I can find only [DimensionProperties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#DimensionProperties) but it needs exact value n pixels.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can achieve it using autoResizeDimensions of Sheets API. You can see the detail information at below links.

#### Endpoint

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/### fileId ###:batchUpdate
```

#### Request body :

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "autoResizeDimensions": {
        "dimensions": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "COLUMNS",
          "startIndex": 0,
          "endIndex": 3
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### References :

- [sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [autoResizeDimensions](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AutoResizeDimensionsRequest)
- [Sample: Automatically resize a column](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#automatically_resize_a_column)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Of course, data needs to exist in the column(s) when executing this request. Silly me... ;)